# How to POST multiple JQuery values using AJAX and avoid object error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

My JQuery code is posting, because the success function is firing. The problem is that the PHP $_POST request is not receiving the data. For debugging purposes, I tried to use alert(data) to display what I hoped would be an array and show me if there was a way to parse whatever was being passed. Instead, the alert box just shows "[object Object]." I need to get this data into a form I can use in PHP for the callback function.

Here's the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//JQuery for the submission of a new list item.
    $('input.[class$="-arrow"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //put e in function.
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

        if ($(this).hasClass('up-arrow')) {
            var arrowdirection = 'up';
            var entry = $(this).val();
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('down-arrow')) {
            var arrowdirection = 'down';
            var entry = $(this).val();
        }

        var data = {
            action: 'cb_lud_arrow_action',
            arrow: arrowdirection,
            entryID: entry
        };

        $.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            datatype: "text",
            success: function(){
                alert(data);
                alert('Thanks for the vote!'); //for debug. Alert is showing! Still not submitting data to database though.
                $('.line-items-rows').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000).fadeIn('fast');
            }
        });
});
});
```

And here's the callback PHP function (which is not updating the database as it should):

```
function cb_lud_arrow_callback(){       
    //Redefine basic variables
    global $wpdb;
    $cb_lud_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $cb_lud_table = $cb_lud_prefix . 'cb_list_up_down';
//find the values posted to the form
    $cb_lud_arrow_keys = array_keys($_POST['arrow']);
    $cb_lud_arrow_values = array_values($_POST['entryID']);
    $cb_lud_entry_id = (int)$cb_lud_arrow_values[2];


        //set some variables to "up" or "down" depending on form input.
            if (strpos($cb_lud_arrow_keys[2], 'up-ID') > 0) {
                $cb_lud_arrow_direction = "up";
            }
            else if (strpos($cb_lud_arrow_keys[2], 'down-ID') > 0) {
                $cb_lud_arrow_direction = "down";
            }
            else {
                $cb_lud_arrow_direction = "nothing";
            }

        //Create the update query that will record the up and down votes.
            //Up votes
            if ($cb_lud_arrow_direction == "up" && $cb_lud_arrow_direction != "nothing") {
                $wpdb->query('UPDATE '.$cb_lud_table.' SET up_votes=up_votes+1
                    WHERE entry_ID='.$cb_lud_entry_id.'');
            }
            //Down votes
            else if ($cb_lud_arrow_direction == "down" && $cb_lud_arrow_direction != "nothing") {
                $wpdb->query('UPDATE '.$cb_lud_table.' SET down_votes=down_votes+1
                    WHERE entry_ID='.$cb_lud_entry_id.'');
            }   

die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firefox and install Firebug. Then go to the Firebug console and execute the jQuery event. It will show you all the AJAX transactions, what was sent, headers, post, etc, and what was received.

Also, you can really shorten your AJAX call to this:

```
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(data){
  $('.line-items-rows').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000).fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Comment: Firebug was very helpful. It looks like the AJAX call is posting the correct data. I saw the following in the POST tab: "action: cb_lud_arrow_action
arrow: up
entryID: 36".  So I'm still lost as to why the database is not updating. But at least this rules out one possible problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome or Firefox to dubug the JQuery.  CTRL+SHIFT+J to get the debugger in chrome not sure about firefox but it's in the options menu.

You will be able to see the values then.

Comment: Thanks. Tried the option in Chrome, but can't see where to find the posted values. Will keep working at it, and if I can get it working, will vote up the answer.

Comment: Under the network setting you will see a list of all the activity.  Click on the item that relates to your ajax url.  or set a break point on the actual ajax call and mouse over the data variable.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm getting "event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future" when looking at the script evaluator.

Comment: If that's a warning only it should affect your ajax call but if that's an error that happens before you ajax call then your ajax call will not be called.

Comment: Thanks. It was just a warning. I'll keep at it.

Answer (score 1):

did you forget the param data in the success function definition?

```
success: function(data){...
```

but not

```
success: function() { ...
```